# Errors on NDK build

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I'm trying to build a wraper using some old C++ code in Android.

When compiling the errors bellow are shown:

```
In file included from /usr/local/android/android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61:0,
                 from /usr/local/android/android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
                 from /usr/local/android/android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/map:60,
                 from /home/vocalize/source/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Lxxxxxxx.h:9,
                 from /home/vocalize/source/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/jni/cxxx_wrap.c:3:
/usr/local/android/android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/functexcept.h:43:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
/usr/local/android/android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/functexcept.h:44:1: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
```

I'm using the following Makefile.mk

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(MY_LIB_DIR)include

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DANDROID_NDK

LOCAL_PATH := $(BASE_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE := cxxxx_lib

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := cxxxx_wrap.c

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := my_lib
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

What I can do to fix these errors?

Comment: if possible then put some code of cxxx_wrap.c file..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A C++ .h file is being included from `cxxx_wrap.c`, which is a .c file. The compiler uses the extension of the source file to detect the language. So it's assuming C, and choking on the C++-specific syntax.

Rename cxxx_wrap.c to .cpp or .cxx. Or surround the `#include "Lxxxxxxx.h"` line with `#ifdef __cplusplus/#endif`. Or force C++ compilation by specifying `-x c++` compiler option.

Once you do, make sure all JNI methods in cxxx_wrap are declared with JNIEXPORT or surrounded with `extern "C" {}`. Otherwise, the Java run-time won't find them.

For the record: renaming the .h file to .hpp won't help.

Comment: Can you post how you solved the problem following these steps?

Comment: Because in my case the C file has some lines which causes errors in C++. So what else option do I have?

Comment: If you have lines that are correct C++ but incorrect C, rename the source file to have the .cpp extension.